# Send a List Parameter to DB2 Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a db2 stored procedure which has an sql statement using the 'recseq In(1,2,3)' syntax.
I have added a parameter(Character(5) to hold the list but in my call statement I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

I have tried call myprocedure(1, '1,2,3') but this generates a Conversion error

Note: call myprocedure(1, '1') will work but just not the list style.

Comment: Which DB2 version are you using? Some versions support arrays as stored procedure parameters.

Comment: The _reason_ this isn't working is because SQL (DB2 or anybody else) doesn't "natively" convert delimited strings to lists; it's treating it as a single piece of data.  If your version doesn't support array parameters (either because of DB2 version, or application language/framework), you can write a function/recursive CTE to split it and return a table.  Otherwise, especially if the list is large, declare a temp table, insert into it, and use that instead.